# Customized color theme switch is not working properly

Tags: flutter, themes, customization

I have created a theme switching project using flutter to switch the theme between 10 different colors, it is working when I use in-built colors available in flutter (like blue, green etc).

But when I use the customized colors the theme is not changing.

Comment: Do you want to change the primary color.?

Comment: Can you show your code?  If you're using ColorScheme.fromSeed, try using  8 digit hex values, like ` ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: const Color(0xff2299aa)),`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.